# How to Stop Alarm android application

Tags: android, alarm

I've to develop an application that remindes the user every 10 minutes with alertDialog during 2 hours ONLY,

I made an application that reminds a user for each 10 minutes, but I want to stop it after 2 hour actually I couldn't do that,

I searched but no answers, if I used amManger.cancel(); it'll cancel the alarm before 2 hour :"(
so, is there any way to do that ? 
and please give an expamle as  I'm new to android...

thanks alooooot ..

-------------- After Updating ---------------------------

```
public class MyAlarm extends Activity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    int i = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startalarm);
        Button buttonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelalarm);
        Button bCancel= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MyAlarm.this, 0,
                new Intent(MyAlarm.this, MyAlarmService.class), 0);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                AlarmManager am2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        firstTime + 10 * 1000, 10 * 1000, pendingIntent);


            }
        });

        bCancel.performClick();
```

---

Question: 
- Where should I put the code to stop the alarm when the bCancel button clicked automatically ??

-and how can I make this click after two hours ???

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
final Button bCancel= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
bCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Your code to stop the alarm goes here.

            }
        });

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                bCancel.performClick();
            }
        }, (2*60*60*1000));
```

Comment: thanks i refer them and most of my code from them, but their alarm didn't stop until the user clicks StopButton, i  need the alarm stop automaticlly after 2 hours  :|

Comment: Then you can click on that button programmatically after two hours if you have any button, by using `performClick()` method.
Put a handler that triggers after 2 hours and then put the code inside. Let me know if any issues.

Comment: I don't have any button to stop that alarm, and I don't know how canu I create a button programmatically !! can you give me any example thanks alot

Comment: You can have a button with visibility set to `View.GONE` and to click on it programmatically-
`Button btn = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.button);
btn.performClick();`

Comment: Also you can do after your 2 hours timer by using handler like-


`new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){


@Override
public void run() {


//Perorm button click here or your own logic to stop alarm.


}, (2*60*60*1000));`

Comment: can you please take look at my question, I hv been updated it thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can create another alarm that will cancel your main alarm after 2 hours. This looks like the simplest solution.

Comment: @user1261835, You should create it together with your main alarm to make sure it will stop the main alarm exactly after 2 hours.