# For loop with AlarmManager Android Application

Tags: java, android, alarm

I'm trying to make a small application that shows a notification for each 10 minutes until reach 2 hours then the alarm should stop, when I used `setRepeat()` it works well but I couldn't stop it as I mentioned in my prevoise question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485358/stopping-alarm-android-application/10486265#10486265),,

I tried with many ways, but it still, there's a problem alarm didn't stop...

I have an idea to use  `mAlarmManager.set()` inside loop, I wrote a code but the loop only start alarm for one time..

so, I'm here to ask how can I implement this idea and showing notification for each 10 minutes until 2 hours !!!

I'll be so appreciated if you help

thanks in advance ...

Comment: You need to accept answers to your questions if you want high quality responses.  Also this is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716573/how-to-stop-alarm-android-application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set alarm within a for loop too.

Example:

```
long next=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCurrentTime + 10*60*1000 + next, pendingIntent);
  next+=10*60*1000;
}
```

Comment: the code i give you is for setting ONE TIME alarm 10 minutes after current time. For loop do this 12 times which means 12*10 = 120minutes=2 hours

And you should change the parameters mCurrentTime and pendingIntent with your variables.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to put it in a loop. Rather, have the alarm's pending intent trigger code that checks how much time has gone by and cancels the alarm if appropriate. (This would go in the onReceive method of the class you created the PendingIntent with.)

Alternatively, you can set another alarm for two hours from the start time which will trigger the code to cancel the repeating alarm.

Comment: thanks for ur response I think ur 1st solution is good but I don't have any idea how can I implement it !! will be appreciated id u explain more ... thanks again

Comment: where should i cancel the alarm if time out !!

Comment: If you post your class that receives the intent from AlarmManager to show your Notification, I'll show you. You probably just want it right on the onReceive() method of that class.